# How to get product Quantity in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, stock, quantity

I need to retrieve product quantity, I found that, the interfaces we used before to get product quantity are deprecated, these are:

```
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem
```

And,

```
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
```

Below link says StockStateInterface is replaced with [Multi Source Inventory](https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/namespace_magento_1_1_inventory.html) but I cannot see a function returning product quantity in it.

https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/interface_magento_1_1_catalog_inventory_1_1_api_1_1_stock_state_interface.html

Is there some other way to get product quantity? I don't want to use deprecated code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code:

```
    <?php


namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Model;

use Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\GetStockIdForCurrentWebsite;
use Magento\InventorySales\Model\GetProductSalableQty;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\GetStockItemDataInterface;

class Stock
{
    /**
     * @var GetProductSalableQty
     */
    private $getProductSalableQty;

    /**
     * @var GetStockIdForCurrentWebsite
     */
    private $getStockIdForCurrentWebsite;

    /**
     * @var GetStockItemDataInterface
     */
    private $getStockItemData;

    /**
     * Stock constructor.
     *
     * @param GetProductSalableQty $getProductSalableQty
     * @param GetStockIdForCurrentWebsite $getStockIdForCurrentWebsite
     * @param GetStockItemDataInterface $getStockItemData
     */
    public function __construct(
        GetProductSalableQty $getProductSalableQty,
        GetStockIdForCurrentWebsite $getStockIdForCurrentWebsite,
        GetStockItemDataInterface $getStockItemData
    ) {
        $this->getProductSalableQty = $getProductSalableQty;
        $this->getStockIdForCurrentWebsite = $getStockIdForCurrentWebsite;
        $this->getStockItemData = $getStockItemData;
    }

    public function getStock($sku)
    {
        $stockId = $this->getStockIdForCurrentWebsite->execute();

        // Actual qty - Reserve Qty - OOS Threshold
        $productQtyInStock = $this->getProductSalableQty->execute($sku, $stockId);
        echo $productQtyInStock . PHP_EOL;

        // Return only qty
        $stockItemData = $this->getStockItemData->execute($sku, $stockId);
        $qty = $stockItemData[GetStockItemDataInterface::QUANTITY];
        echo $qty . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

You can get salable qty or total Qty using the above code.